# "everyone should go to jail FOR when they make a mistake"?

Tags: grammar

> "Yes, I do think he should go to jail, everyone should go to jail for
>   when they make a mistake," said Kim Ballinger, the victim's domestic
>   partner.

From this link: http://abc7ny.com/news/nypd-officer-peter-liang-found-guilty-of-manslaughter-in-stairwell-shooting-that-killed-akai-gurley/1196360/

Isn't that "for" redundant and breaking the whole sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , the "for" is redundant - it is incorrect.

Everyone should go to jail for the mistakes they make

OR

Everyone should go to jail when they make mistakes    (or a mistake)